# Upload a huge file in SharePoint (3 GB)

Tags: file-upload

I am looking for a way to upload file in SharePoint in different parts(or chunks).
I.e. if file is of 3 GB, then sending 20 MB chunks of data in different requests.
and all the chunks merge on server side and uploaded as file.

I think I can do this by uploading 20 MB of data as file and then append that data to the file.
But I don't no the way how to instruct server to append data from client side.

Or is there any other better or preferable way to do this?

I want to do this from client side i.e. client object model or web service,
but client object model is preferable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SharePoint 2013 has a Maximum file size of 2GB, so no matter how you upload the file it can never be larger than 2GB. For 2010 this limit is much lower.

Comment: yep, max size is a hard limit dictated by SQL blob size (2 GB for both SP2010 and SP2013). Also uploading large files to SharePoint is usually sign of a bad design and in general a bad idea!